# backend urls broken in yii 2 advanced template

Tags: apache, .htaccess, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

After enabling pretty urls in site and setting up apache virtualhost, navigation is broken on backend, returns #404 for all pages.

Here are configuration files:

httpd-vhosts.conf file:

```
...
<VirtualHost nvp.dev>
  Alias /backend "d:/dev/htdocs/nvp/backend/web/"
  DocumentRoot "d:/dev/htdocs/nvp/frontend/web/"
  ServerName nvp.dev
  ServerAlias www.nvp.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
# If a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . /index.php
```

common\config\main-local.php

```
'components' => [
  ...
  'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
    ],
]
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed.

In case if someone has similar problem:

```
RewriteBase /backend
```

Needs to be added in `.htaccess,` located at `backend/web` directory.